# Function not working when placed in js file

Tags: javascript

Hi this is working when I include the code inside of my html but when I shift it out into myScript.js I get no results, can anyone point out where I've gone wrong with this as I'd like to be able to access this function across several pages?

I've also got the side issue that if I enter something, then delete the input value my filtered array shows all the options, is it possible to set this to a "" value if the input box contains no value?

Thanks

```js
    function page_search(){
     var pages = [
     {name: "Test",url: "Test.html"},
     {name: "Rest",url: "Rest.html"},
     {name: "Best",url: "Best.html"},     
     ];
     
     let input = document.getElementById('searchbar').value 
     input=input.toLowerCase();
     let x = document.getElementById('searchresults');
     var results = [];
      for(var i=0;i<pages.length;i++){
       if(pages[i].name.toLowerCase().indexOf(input) > -1)
        results.push("<a href='"+pages[i].url+"' target='_blank'>"+pages[i].name+"</a>")
      }
       if(results.length == 0)
        $(x).html("No Results Found");
       else
        $(x).html(results.join("<br>"));
     return results;
    }
```

```html
    <html>
    <head>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="myScript.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="searchbar">
       <input type="text" id="searchbar" onkeyup="page_search()" placeholder="" value="Search.." maxlenght="25" autocomplete="off"/>
    </div>
    <div  id="searchresults"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Your script runs in the head before the body is rendered, so your `document.getElementById('searchbar')` (for example) might return nothing. As a first step, you could try moving your script to the bottom of your body tag, and see if this solves any issues.

Answer (score 0):

I have added the code, it will definitely resolve your second issue of displaying "" when input box is empty. I am not able to replicate your first issue, can you please tell what is error you are getting ?

```js
function page_search() {
  var pages = [{
      name: "Test",
      url: "Test.html"
    },
    {
      name: "Rest",
      url: "Rest.html"
    },
    {
      name: "Best",
      url: "Best.html"
    },
  ];

  let input = $('#searchbar').val().toLowerCase()
  let x = $('#searchresults');
  var results = [];
  if (input) {
    for (var i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) {
      if (pages[i].name.toLowerCase().indexOf(input) > -1) {
        results.push(`<a href="${pages[i].url}" target="_blank">${pages[i].name}</a>`);
      }
    }
  } else {
    $(x).html("");
    return;
  }
  if (results.length == 0)
    $(x).html("No Results Found");
  else
    $(x).html(results.join("<br>"));
}

var ele = document.getElementById('searchbar');
ele.addEventListener('keyup', page_search);
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="searchbarC">
    <input type="text" id="searchbar" placeholder="Search.." maxlenght="25" />
  </div>
  <div id="searchresults"></div>
 <script src="myScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Jasdeep! I get this error: Uncaught ReferenceError: page_search is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onkeyup (Test.html:21)
onkeyup @ Test.html:21

Comment: ok, I don't have idea why its not working. It is working at my end.
I can suggest you to change function definition, I am updating my code please check.

Comment: Seems both ways of declaring the function work with the script inside the html, but as soon as I remove it from the html file and drop it in myScript.js file, this is when I get the error.

Comment: Is your html and js file in same directory/folder ?

Comment: updated my code and converted into jquery format as well, it should work